# Include classes in a groovy script

Tags: class, groovy, include

How can I include a few classes in a Groovy script?

(This question has nothing to do with REST, but I use REST to put the question in the right context)

Background:
I am developing a CLI in groovy to get status information from a service we are running. The status information is exposed as a REST interface.

Depending on the argument I give on the CLI, different paths are called on the REST interface. I have also put the actual REST communication in a class hierarchy to be able to reuse the code and this is where I have the problem. How can I include the class hierarchy in my groovy script in an easy way?

Groovy CLI-script `RestCli.groovy`

```
import restcli.RestA
import restcli.RestB

if(args[0] == "A") {
    new RestA().restCall()
}
else if(args[0] == "B") {
    new RestB().restCall()
}
```

Super class for the hierarcy `restcli/RestSuper.groovy`

```
package restcli

abstract class RestSuper {

    protected def restCall(String path) {
        println 'Calling: ' +path
    } 

    abstract def restCall()

}
```

Two classes to implement different calls. `restcli/RestA.groovy`

```
package restcli

class RestA extends RestSuper {

    def restCall() {
        restCall("/rest/AA")
    }       

}
```

and `restcli/RestB.groovy`

```
package restcli

class RestB extends RestSuper {

    def restCall() {
        restCall("/rest/BB")
    }

}
```

The result I want to get is simply:

```
> groovy RestCli.groovy B
Calling: /rest/BB
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

I would actually like to avoid creating a jar file and then use the `-classpath` option, because I'm also using `@Grab` to get http-builder and if I use `-classpath` then I'm getting problems like this one: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put multiple classes in one groovy script (not sure how/if packages work that way) or just create the package structure as a directory structure in the same folder as your main script.

In your example that could look like this:

```
/
+ RestCli.groovy
+ restcli/
+--+ RestSuper.groovy
+--+ RestA.groovy
+--+ RestB.groovy
```

You could then call your script like this:

```
> groovy RestCli.groovy B
```

Comment: Thank you! Very simple solution.